# How to resolve name error on variable in class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am making my first model, and I'm creating an upload system which uploads to a folder with the name of the user uploading it.

For some reason, I get this error when I try to create an object from the model:

```
NameError at /admin/tracks/track/add/
name '_Track__user_name' is not defined
```

Here's my models.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

# Create your models here.


class Track(models.Model):

    user_name = "no_user"

    def get_username():
        user_name = "no_user"
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user_name = request.user.username
        else:
            user_name = "DELETE"

    def generate_user_folder_tracks(instance, filename):
        return "uploads/users/%s/tracks/%s" % (user_name, filename)

    def is_mp3(value):
        if not value.name.endswith('.mp3'):
            raise ValidationError(u'You may only upload mp3 files for tracks!')

    def generate_user_folder_art(instance, filename):
        return "uploads/users/%s/art/%s" % (user_name, filename)

    def is_square_png(self):
        if not self.name.endswith('.png'):
            raise ValidationError("You may only upload png files for album art!")
        else:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(self)
            if not h == w:
                raise ValidationError("This picture is not square! Your picture must be equally wide as its height.")
            else:
                if not (h + w) >= 1000:
                    raise ValidationError("This picture is too small! The minimum dimensions are 500 by 500 pixels.")
        return self


    # Variables

    track_type_choices = [
        ('ORG', 'Original'),
        ('RMX', 'Remix'),
        ('CLB', 'Collab'),
        ('LIV', 'Live'),
    ]

    # Model Fields

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=7500)
    track_type = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                                 choices=track_type_choices,
                                 default='ORG')

    track_type_content = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    created = models.TimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_tracks,validators=[is_mp3])
    albumart = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_art,validators=[is_square_png])
```

As you can see from the first line after the class is defined, there is clearly a variable called "user_name", and when using my upload functions, it is supposed to use this variable for the folder name.

I am very confused to why this is throwing an error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the actual error occur?

Comment: It occurs when I try to use the model through the admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some serious problems with variable scope here. Just defining an attribute called "user_name" at the top of the class does not automatically give you access to it elsewhere in the class; you would need to access it via the class itself. Usually you do that through the `self` variable that is the first parameter to every method.

However, many of your methods do not even accept a `self` parameter, so they would give TypeError when they are called. On top of that, your `user_name` attribute is actually a class attribute, which would be shared by all instances of User - this would clearly be a bad thing. You should really make it a Django field, like the other attributes.

Finally, your scope issues worsen when you try and access `request` in one of those methods. Again, you can't access a variable unless it has been passed to that method (or is available in global scope, which the request is definitely not). So `get_username` cannot work at all.

I must say though that all that is irrelevant, as the error you get does not even match your code: you must have accessed `Track.__user_name` somewhere to get that error.

Comment: Okay, so why do I need self parameters on all my functions? Also, what would be the correct way of getting the username of the current user, and then putting it as the folder name for the uploaded file?

Comment: Actually, I see that these methods are being assigned as `upload_to`, so assuming this is Python 3, it might work - although better to explicitly decorate them as `@staticmethods`. And the way to assign the username it is to define `user` as a ForeignKey on your model, set it automatically in [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) and access it via the `instance` argument.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that? I am not very familiar with ForeignKey and would like to know how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a variable username, but its not a field which would mean that the query set it looks like you're creating won't find it

```
user_name = "no_user"
```

should be one of the following

```
user_name = models.CharField(default='no_user')
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
```

The only reason I've suggested a `CharField` here is incase you don't use some form of authorisation user model in your app. If you do, then you should use a foreign key to that model.